# Ubuntu: OpenJDK 8 - Unable to locate package

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

So I just installed Ubuntu, and this is my first time working in a Linux environment, so bear with my noobishness here.

Anyway, I downloaded the Java 8 JDK directly from Oracle, but I understand there's also an OpenJDK for Java 8 as well. I have two questions.

1. What is the difference between the Oracle version and OpenJDK. Pros/Cons?
2. When I try and get OpenJDK 8, I can't. I'm pasting the terminal command and the error message I get here, hoping for advice. Again, very new to Linux, been on my first Linux distro ever for less than an hour here at this point.

   ```
   user@computer:~/Java$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk
   ```

Any help would be appreciated. In the meantime, I'm just gonna use the Oracle package. Thanks.

Edit:

So, now I have a new problem. I installed OpenJDK 7, it came with Maven and just installed before I realized I was getting a two-for-one deal. Now I have JDK 7, and Eclipse, and Maven, and they're all working, but I'm stuck on JDK 7 rather than 8.

I saw that there's a link below, I intend to check it out in the morning, it's 2am and I'm tired right now. Any other advice for this new issue would be appreciated, otherwise I will definitely be checking out that link first thing in the morning.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openjdk-8-jdk

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?  The latest couple of versions have had it available as an installation option.

Comment: Stephen's link will resolve your issue :)

Comment: Thanks. It's 2am, so I'm going to bed, but I'll check the link in the morning. I added an edit to my question with an additional issue, if you could look it over that would be great. If the existing link/answer will help with that too, I apologize for being too tired to look at it right now, I'll be checking it out in the morning.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 14.10 I believe. Whatever the most recent long term release was.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

**UPDATE**: installation without root privileges below

---

I advise you to not install packages manually on ubuntu system if there is already a (semi-official) repository able to solve your problem. Further, use Oracle JDK for development, just to avoid (very sporadic) compatibility issues (i've tried many years ago, it's surely better now).

Add the *webupd8* repo to your system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Install your preferred version of jdk (versions from java-6 to java-9 available):

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

---

You can also install multiple version of jdk, mixing openjdk and oracle versions. 
Then you can use the command *update-java-alternatives* to switch between installed version:

```
# list available jdk
update-java-alternatives --list

# use jdk7
sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-7-oracle

# use jdk8
sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-8-oracle
```

**Requirements**

If you get `add-apt-repository: command not found` be sure to have `software-properties-common` installed:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

If you're using an older version Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

---

**JDK installation without root privileges**

If you haven't administrator rights on your target machine your simplest bet is to use `sdkman` to install the zulu certified openjdk:

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
sdk install java
```

*NOTE*: sdkman allow to install also the official Oracle JDK, although it's not a the default option. View available versions with:

```
sdk ls java
```

Install the chosen version with:

```
sdk install java <version>
```

For example:

```
sdk install java 9.0.1-oracle
```

---

**Glossary of commands**

- **sudo** `<command> [command_arguments]`: execute a command with the superuser privilege.
- **add-apt-repository** `<PPA_id>`: Ubuntu (just like every Debian derivatives and generally speaking every Linux distribution) has a main repository of packages that handle things like package dependencies and updating. In Ubuntu is possible to extend the main repository using a PPA (Personal Package Archive) that usually contains packages not available in the system (just like oracle jdk) or updated versions of available ones (example: LibreOffice 5 in LTS is available only through this [PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu)).
- **apt-get** `[install|update|upgrade|purge|...]`: it's "the" command-line package handler used to manipulate the *state* of every repository on the system (installing / updating / upgrading can be viewed as an alteration of the repository current state).

*In our case*: with the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java` we inform the system that the next repository update must retrieve packages information also from webupd8 repo.

With `sudo apt-get update` we actually update the system repository (all this operations requires superuser privileges, so we prepend *sudo* to the commands).

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

- **update-java-alternatives** (a specific java version of **update-alternatives**): in Ubuntu several packages provides the same functionality (browse the internet, compile mails, edit a text file or provides java/javac executables...). To allows the system to choose the user favourites tool given a specific task a mechanism using [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) under `/etc/alternatives/` is used. Try to update the jdk as indicated above (switch between java 7 and java 8) and view how change the output of this command:

  `ls -l /etc/alternatives/java*`

*In our case*: `sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-8-oracle` update symlinks under /etc/alternatives to point to java-8-oracle executables.

**Extras:**

- **man** `<command>`: start using man  to read a really well written and detailed help on (almost) every shell command and its options (every command i mention in this little answer has a man page, try `man update-java-alternatives`).
- **apt-cache** `search <search_key>`: query the APT cache to search for a package related with the search_key provided (can be the package name or some word in package description).
- **apt-cache** `show <package>`: provides APT information for a specific package (package version, installed or not, description).

Comment: The problem is I get a message "Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer". Same thing happens when I try and get openjdk 8 using the sudo apt-get command.

Comment: And nevermind that last comment, forgot to do the repo update you put there. At the moment, it appears to be downloading the update.

On a semi-related note, could you include info about the linux commands you put here, like I said I just started using linux and I want to learn as much as I can.

I'll also mention more about if this is working once the download is complete.

Comment: Nice! Installed and working, thanks!!! If you could provide info on what exactly you just had me do, so I can understand it in the future, that'd be great. Again, I'm a linux noob, I only just started running it for the first time.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer, i've added a glossary of commands used (and some hints)

Comment: Notably, this is (at least labeled as) the Oracle commercial version of java, not the open community version (openjre).

Comment: @basZero: seems you need to install software properties: `apt-get install software-properties-common`. I'll update the post consequently to include this requirement. Thanks

Comment: This answer is not valid - oracle prohibits direct downloads of java installer. sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer fails

Comment: @AlecIstomin: I've tried the procedure from with a cold start just now and everything is working fine as usual (the jdk is downloaded directly from the Oracle servers). Maybe is it something related with a restriction in your local network? Can you try again in a "clean" environment?

Comment: I might try later, but what I got instead of java archive was an HTML page from oracle with explanation how to accept license and then download

Comment: I've been trying to solve this issue for 4 hours already. Thanks for this awesome solution!

Comment: `ppa:webupd8team/java` was discontinued, and `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` does not work. When you add the PPA, you get this message: *'Oracle Java downloads now require logging in to an Oracle account to download Java updates, like the latest Oracle Java 8u211 / Java SE 8u212. Because of this I cannot update the PPA with the latest Java (and the old links were broken by Oracle).'*

Comment: @RKiselev: thank you for your feedback, I will update the answer accordingly after some tests. In the meantime, since a lot of relyable options are available now, I would suggest to use the instructions above to install `sdkman` and go with a simple `sdk install java 8.0.242-open` or `8.0.242-zulu`

Comment: @GiuseppeRicupero sdkman is not working to download java 8.0.242-open, it says "Can not install java 8.0.242-open at this time..." and it appears to be giving an SSL SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version curl error in a weird one-character-per-line way.

Comment: @jotadepicas be sure to have the latest updated version of sdkman. Run `sdk update` before installing. If a new version is installed, close and reopen the terminal to use the new sdkman version. I have just tried and, after an update, it has installed `java 8.0.242-open` as expected.

Comment: @GiuseppeRicupero thanks, could be. Couldn't reproduce because I'm trying to make an ancient ubuntu 12.04 box work, now I realize most probably those TLS handshake errors are because of that.

Answer (score 134):

As you can see I only have java 1.7 installed (on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine).

```
update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

To install Java 8, I did,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Afterwards, now I have java 7 and 8,

```
update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 1069 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

**BONUS ADDED (how to switch between different versions)**

- run the follwing command from the terminal:

> `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
>
> ```
> There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
>
>   Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>   0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
>   1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
> * 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1069      manual mode
>
> Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
> ```

As you can see I'm running open jdk 8. To switch to to jdk 7, press `1` and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Do the same for `javac` as well with, `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`.

Check versions to confirm the change: `java -version` and `javac -version`.

Comment: Very useful for I didn't know which repo was required to install OpenJDK ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @cram2208 glad that helped you. thanks for the comment.

Comment: Is the openjdk-r safe enough for server?

Comment: Thanks for detail answer, this solution is perfectly work for me.

Comment: If `add-apt-repository command is not found` run the below command

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Answer (score 18):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get  install openjdk-8-jdk
```

this should work

Comment: Please add an explanation what this adds to the existing answers.

Comment: I was using the WSL2 from Windows, and I forgot to update the packages before installing the OpenJDK and got the same error. @GertArnold, the answer of Zoe helped me in that scenario.

Comment: Why is this answer at the bottom? Can we please upvote it to go to the top ;-)

Answer (score 14):

I'm getting OpenJDK 8 from the official Debian repositories, rather than some random PPA or non-free Oracle binary.  Here's how I did it:

`sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring`

Make `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-jessie-backports.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main
```

Make `/etc/apt/preferences.d/debian-jessie-backports`:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian,a=jessie-backports
Pin-Priority: -200
```

Then finally do the install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: And final finally 
`update-alternatives --config java ;-)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the only solution that worked for me (Deb 8)

Answer (score 13):

I've been searching the internet for an answer on this. I have a Debian 10 server installation.

I had the same problem with installing openjdk-8-jdk. An `apt install` resulted in `package not found`.

The other comment here helps you install the oracle jdk 8, but I wanted to use the openjdk 8.

What I discovered is that for Debian 10, by default, only the openjdk-11 packages are installable without adding a ppa, however for Debian 9 (stretch), by default, you can install openjdk-8 packages. Therefore, adding the stretch Debian ppa allowed me to install openjdk-8 packages.

Adding the Debian stretch ppa.

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main'
```

Then update and install openjdk-8-jdk

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Answer (score 7):

i have same problem by installing
`openjdk-8-jdk` on ubuntu and on kali but failed then i found program is not listed in the repository list so i solved it by adding PPA (personal package archive These are unofficial repositories).

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install software-properties-common`

`sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main'`

`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and tried all of the solutions on this page but none of them did the trick.

What finally worked was adding the `universe` repo to my repo list. To do that run the following command

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

After running the above command I was able to run

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

without an issue and the package was installed.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Not sure why I've been downvoted for this answer. If there is something incorrect or a potential issue please leave a comment to help others and myself understand better.

Comment: Getting this error in add-apt repository 0.482 Error: 'universe' invalid

Answer (score 2):

Run the below commands... Issue resovled :)

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common -y

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably coming in late, but it saved me a lot:

On Ubuntu, Search and click on **Software and Updates**. The following page loads. Make sure you check the appropriate boxes under **Downloadable from the internet**. When these are unchecked, several packages don't get found.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Personally I tried a bunch of these solutions none of which worked for me, eventually though I found this worked.

`sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main'`

Then to install openjdk 8.

`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

Answer (score 0):

After adding the `JDK` repo, before Installing you might want to run an update first so the repo can be added
run 
`apt update`

an then continue with your installation 
`sudo apt install adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot`

Answer (score 0):

openjdk-8 is now out of support so I used AdoptOpenJDK8 instead.

Here is the command:

```bash
sudo apt-get update --yes && \
    apt-get install --yes gnupg2 apt-transport-https && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A1EAC8B7 && \
    echo 'deb https://rpardini.github.io/adoptium-deb-installer stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rpardini-adoptium.list && \
    apt-get update --yes && \
    apt-get install --yes adoptium-8-installer
```

based on https://github.com/rpardini/adoptium-deb-installer?tab=readme-ov-file#for-debian

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem on windows10 when i installed Ubuntu as Subsystem (terminal) on win10 , I tried many things to fix this issue, but I could download openjdk-8-jdk by installing Kali Linux (terminal) instead of Ubuntu on win10.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

Try; openjdk-11-jdk and default-jdk

Or :

Update  all packages with :

```
Sudo apt-get install updates
```

Then go to root , download the java version you want and extract.
(If you don't know manual install try the recommended codes in the discussion)

Change the environment libraries (java) with oracle.com guides for each,long process but magical