# Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer linux mint

Tags: linux, java-8

I m having

```
 java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.13.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

trying to update above to latest version by following commands :-

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

But i am getting following error :-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
```

I even tried this link :- [Ubuntu: OpenJDK 8 - Unable to locate package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942023/ubuntu-openjdk-8-unable-to-locate-package)

My Java Path :-

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Can anyone help me on this ,Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need oracle jdk 8? Because you currently have openjdk, so why not update that?

Comment: i even try sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk but was getting error saying  Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk , Actually i just updated my Android SDK to N and Android N requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 , so i am updating it

Comment: I assume the PPA is being added and the update throws no errors? Otherwise, I'm not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use command: apt-cache search oracle* to search package name is present.

Answer (score -1):

This is a reliable way of installing the latest JDK on Debian based Linux.

`echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-$(lsb_release -cs).list && \
    echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated oracle-java8-installer && \
    apt install -y oracle-java8-set-default`