# Do I need to install JRE8

Tags: version, java

I created a Java application with Java 8.

I've deployed it to a server and got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Rest : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

When I ran java -version I got the following:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.8) (7u121-2.6.8-1ubuntu0.14.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.121-b00, mixed mode)
```

I haven't seen this before. Do I need to install JRE 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word - yes.

Running classes of version 52 requires JRE 8.

Comment: Cheers. After a little Googling I found it. Here's a link to updating it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942023/ubuntu-openjdk-8-unable-to-locate-package