# Failed to run "javac -version" make sure that you have a JDK version 8 installed

Tags: java, ionic-framework, javac

I am new to ionic and I have tried everything available on the internet regarding this issue but i haven`t found any suitable/matching solution.

Details of my problem :

I am working with ionic 5 and when I am running `ionic cordova run android` then after a while I have got the following error :

```
Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK version 8 installed.
You can get it from the following location:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
    
    cordova build android --device exited with exit code 1.
    
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

I have already installed java, cordova and android studio on my PC(ubuntu 16.04) following are some details :

command : `java -version`

result  :

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~16.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

command : `javac -version`
result  :

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-5-jdk
 * openjdk-8-jdk-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jdk
 * gcj-4.9-jdk
 * openjdk-9-jdk-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-install default-jdk`, which is basically what that last message is telling you to do, should do the trick.

Debian/Ubuntu have different packages for the JRE and the JDK. You installed the JRE only.

Comment: It didn't worked,
after running the command i have got the following msg :

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree      
 
Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package default-openjdk

and then i have searched with the last line of the message and tried that also and it didnt worked either.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942023/ubuntu-openjdk-8-unable-to-locate-package

Comment: Please try `default-jdk` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked but after resolving this issue another issue has come.
I have tried to add the java sdk path to .bashrc and .bash_profile as well 
but nothing works

Comment: Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/ge/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/ge/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova build android --device exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

Comment: I'd say you need to install gradle, but this is another question entirely. You should do some research on that error and, in case, open a different question.

Answer (score 2):

I realized this doesn't have to just end with eliminating the error by installing the Java Development Kit. Since this is an Ionic project, you'd face other problems if you don't specifically install Open JDK 8 and properly set your environment variables -- Cordova currently supports only Open JDK8, and going with a newer version might generate the warning message:

```
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.9
```

So after dealing with this and all subsequent errors, I thought I should elaborate the solution that completely worked for me:

**First**, Install the Default Java runtime environment (JRE)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install default-jre
```

**Second**, Install the Java Development Kit (JDK) ***version 8***

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

To verify that both are installed, run `java -version` for JRE and  `javac -version` for JDK

**Third**, set the `JAVA_HOME` Environment Variable. You'd have to determine where Java is installed to be able to do this. You can determine that by running:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Your installation path will most likely be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`. Copy the path, right before the `/bin/java` portion and add it among your environment variables by pasting it right at the end of the `/etc/environment` file.

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

The end of the file should look like:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
```

Save the file, close the editor and apply the changes by running

```
source /etc/environment
```

You can be sure this is set by running

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Finally, and this seems to happen only to me, I have to restart my machine to make sure the changes get applied globally

Credits: [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04)