# Cant login in to my server. Not anyone can

Tags: java, server, minecraft

This is the error that might be causing it... Any ideas? The server did not close properly since my computer got shut down... It was after that it stopped working, the server is starting properly but you can't join. It might be this error,

```
[17:29:57] [Server console handler/ERROR]: [TerminalConsole] Failed to read console input
java.io.IOException: Referensen (handle) är felaktig
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:271) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:282) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:297) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:339) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:178) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:329) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:396) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecrell.terminalconsole.SimpleTerminalConsole.readCommands(SimpleTerminalConsole.java:180) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-562]
    at net.minecrell.terminalconsole.SimpleTerminalConsole.start(SimpleTerminalConsole.java:143) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-562]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer$1.run(DedicatedServer.java:106) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-562]
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Referensen (handle) är felaktig
        at java.io.FileDescriptor.close0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FileDescriptor.close(FileDescriptor.java:297) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FileInputStream$1.close(FileInputStream.java:366) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FileDescriptor.closeAll(FileDescriptor.java:355) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.close(FileInputStream.java:364) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.close(BufferedInputStream.java:481) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implClose(StreamDecoder.java:391) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.close(StreamDecoder.java:204) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.close(InputStreamReader.java:193) ~[?:?]
        at java.io.BufferedReader.close(BufferedReader.java:532) ~[?:?]
        at net.minecrell.terminalconsole.SimpleTerminalConsole.readCommands(SimpleTerminalConsole.java:183) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-562]
        at net.minecrell.terminalconsole.SimpleTerminalConsole.start(SimpleTerminalConsole.java:143) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-562]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer$1.run(DedicatedServer.java:106) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Paper-562]
```

Comment: Looks like it's trying to read from a file and failing.

Comment: Yeah, I can join the server on localhost but not with wan. It worked a couple of hours ago and it has been working for 3 weeks, I don't know what has happened. I have updated java, paper and checked my firewall and my router for the port forwarding, but everything seems to be as it should. My friend couldn't connect either... It seems to be launching correctly and everything like that, it's not a plugin that causes it since I can join on a local host. The port forwarding as I said seems to be working as well. But something with the hosting, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Which minecraft version are you running? I had lots of troubles with old minecraft versions (1.12 and under) due to java versions. I couldn't join and it was crashing the server.

Do `java -version`. If your java version isn't 1.8, this may help you :
[Ubuntu: OpenJDK 8 - Unable to locate package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942023/ubuntu-openjdk-8-unable-to-locate-package) (for linux and macos)

Check out the `JDK installation without root privileges` and install java sdk 8...
Then it'll ask you if you want to set it as the default java version and type `y`.

If you're on windows, search up how to change your default java version.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it. It was just that my public IP address had updated and with that my domain didn't work since it had my old IP. So either get a static IP or just update your domain to your new IP address.